# whats wrong if i use wrapper class instead of final variable for local class

Tags: java

I was trying the understand the concept of local class & final variables. I had this code from java docs. As far as i understood, the local classes can only take final variables from its enclosing block. In the below code its ok if i declare **final int numberLength = 10;** but again wrapper classes are immutable & final. So, whats wrong if i declare it as  **Integer numberLength=new Integer(7);**?

```
public class LocalClassExample {

static String regularExpression = "[^0-9]";

public static void validatePhoneNumber(
    String phoneNumber1, String phoneNumber2) {

   // final int numberLength = 10;
    Integer numberLength=new Integer(7);
    // Valid in JDK 8 and later:

    // int numberLength = 10;

    class PhoneNumber {

        String formattedPhoneNumber = null;

        PhoneNumber(String phoneNumber){
            // numberLength = 7;
            String currentNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll(
              regularExpression, "");
            if (currentNumber.length() == numberLength)
                formattedPhoneNumber = currentNumber;
            else
                formattedPhoneNumber = null;
        }

        public String getNumber() {
            return formattedPhoneNumber;
        }

        // Valid in JDK 8 and later:

 //            public void printOriginalNumbers() {
//                System.out.println("Original nubmers are " + phoneNumber1 +
//                    " and " + phoneNumber2);
//            }
    }

    PhoneNumber myNumber1 = new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber1);
    PhoneNumber myNumber2 = new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber2);

    // Valid in JDK 8 and later:

//        myNumber1.printOriginalNumbers();

    if (myNumber1.getNumber() == null) 
        System.out.println("First number is invalid");
    else
        System.out.println("First number is " + myNumber1.getNumber());
    if (myNumber2.getNumber() == null)
        System.out.println("Second number is invalid");
    else
        System.out.println("Second number is " + myNumber2.getNumber());

 }

 public static void main(String... args) {
    validatePhoneNumber("123-456-7890", "456-7890");
 }
}
```

Comment: you said it yourself: variables must be final. `Integer numberLength=new Integer(7);` is not final.

Comment: `Integer`class is declared as final. But, in your case, the compiler expects the variable `numberLength` to be final.
There is a difference between immutability and final. If you want more explanation, see [this link](http://www.dailyfreecode.com/forum/differences-between-final-immutable-22998.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you declare

```
Integer numberLength=new Integer(7);
```

you could still later assign another value to `numberLength`. This is not allowed if `numberLength` is used in an inner class.

Answer (score 0):

The final operator does not actually require that the variable it is acting on be `immutible`. It is actually just forcing the variable to not be `reassignable`. You can reassign the variable in the case where you have the `Integer` type even though `Integer` itself is `immutible`.

Answer (score 0):

Inner classes can access member from their enclosing class. However, in your example, `numberLength` is not a class member, but a variable, therefore inaccessible for class `PhoneNumber` unless declared static.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a local variable visible to a method of the inner class, the compiler must copy the variable's value into a place where the inner class can access it. References to the same variable may use different code sequences in different places, as long as the same value is produced everywhere, so that the name consistently appears to refer to the same variable in all parts of its scope.

By convention, a local variable like array is copied into a private field val$array of the inner class. (Because array is final, such copies never contain inconsistent values.) Each copied value is passed to the inner class constructor as a separate argument of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

In Next Line if U assign like this,

```
numberLength=12;
```

you discarded previous value and created an new numberLength object with value 12.The previous value cannot be changed instead new instance will be created.But if you assign it as final you cannot override it's value.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a local class with referring to a variable in the enclosing scope, the compiler generates a (hidden) field in that local class in which it copies the value of the used variable. That said, the compiler must make sure that the variable's value cannot be changed. For this reason the variable must be final, as this is the keyword that ensures that the value is fixed.

Summarizing: It does not matter that the class Integer is final (which it is as part of the immutable concept). The variable you are referring to must be declared as final.